# how to hide element through the css style

Tags: html, css, styles

I just started programming and I tried to hide element with css but working on mobile side

**element:**

[image]

**html:**

[image]

**style:**

[image]

What do I have to write in style to hide that element?

Comment: which element do you want to hide

Comment: in 1st(element) image i have to hide that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - IMAGES OF CODE ARE NOT A SUITABLE REPLACEMENT.

Comment: Is .ltr-direction { display: none} not working for you or what the image class you used for

Answer (score 0):

Use the `display: none` property to the whole class.

```
.bottom .right .round {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to hide an element with CSS. One of them is to use `display: none;`

Since you didn't mention if other HTML elements use the same class as your element, your best best would be to provide a CSS rule that targets the element's id. In this case it appears the id is `tawkchat-minified-wrapper`. The CSS selector for ids is `#`.

So your CSS rule would be:

```
#tawkchat-minified-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Be aware that, without the full HTML, it's hard to know if that's the right DOM element to target, since from your screen capture it seems it could also be its parent, with id `tawkchat-minified-box`. If you provide more of the HTML, maybe this would be apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none` with media query for display in mobile view, you can define `max-width` where you want to show your div.

```
.ltr-direction{
  display:none;
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .ltr-direction{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it simply using `display: none` But it will be much more easily understandable if you have shared more lines of code.

As ID is considered to be unique, in your case you should use it for hiding purpose. Hope the below code will help you:

`#tawkchat-minified-wrapper {display: none;}`